# Setting the color of a linkbutton at startup via ForeColor property based on Eval data pulled from database ASP.net/C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, repeater, linkbutton

So, what i'm trying to do is pretty straight forward. The idea is to set the text color of a linkbutton using the ForeColor property using an inline query that sets the color based on the value of the Eval being checked. As it is right now (see code below) it works fine for two colors, as a simple binary if/else inline query. The problem is basically that I would like to figure out a way to add more options or nest the inline query to allow more choices (shooting for 10) which I haven't been able to figure out how to do.

Note that the linkbutton in question is inside a repeater and therefore out of scope to simply do this with a method, which ideally is what I would have liked to have done. Anyways, here is the code i'm working with, and the language in question is ASP.net/C#:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lblFromUser" Text='<%# Eval("fromuser") %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>' OnCommand="test" ForeColor='<%# ((Eval("sendertype").Equals("Admin")) || Eval("sendertype").Equals("Moderator")) ? System.Drawing.Color.Orange : System.Drawing.Color.DarkTurquoise %>' Font-Underline="false" Font-Size="small" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a function on code behind With parameter of your item type then return the color? Like this:

.cs File:

```
Protected  System.Drawing.Color generateColor(ItemType input)
{
   ((Eval("sendertype").Equals("Admin")) || Eval("sendertype").Equals("Moderator")) ? System.Drawing.Color.Orange : System.Drawing.Color.DarkTurquoise
}
```

Markup page:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lblFromUser" Text='<%# Eval("fromuser") %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>' OnCommand="test" ForeColor='<%# generateColor((ItemType)Container.DataItem))%>' Font-Underline="false" Font-Size="small" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it didn't work. Though I suspect that even if it had i'd end up with the same issue I started with